# magento can the associated products of a configurable product inherit details?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have created a configurable product so that I can add sizes to my products and each individual associated product can have a quantity unique to the certain sizes of product.

However I have 5 different sizes; extra small, small, medium, large and extra large.

This means I have to create 5 products per every single product and as the; name, short_description, long_description, price, tax, etc.. all are required fields i find myself repeating the data a ridiculous amount of times, and its just not realistic way to run the system.

Is there a way that and associated products i create will inherit the attributes of their parent? Literally all i want to be able to have unique is the size and quantity?

Magento Experts please help?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please share the details with us or mark my answer as solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: btw when you create a configurable product, and switch to the tab "Associatied products" you can "quick create" products. I think there is all the standard information, like short and ling description copied.

Answer (score 2):

Within the configurable product, just select 'Associated Products' at the bottom of the left hand menu and you can 'Quick Create' as many simple products as you like that inherit the same details as the configurable product meaning you don't have to repeat all the information.

As already stated, you can also set any attributes to become not required from the 'Manage Attributes' section. Setting any such as the short description and description attributes to 'Values Required = No' will allow you to save any products with these fields empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the attributes to be `required`.

Go to the backend `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Short Description/... > Values Required > No`.

Comment: But will this mean that the values are inherited? I have noticed when i add images to the configurable product and not to the associated ones they do not inherit an image

Comment: the standard case is, that the simple products are visibile "neither in catalog nor search" (not alone), I know only the german translation at the moment. Therefore the user sees only the configurable product and the simples are only used internally. And the (short) description is never readable.

Answer (score 0):

What few will tell you is that, when creating configurable products you should **click *save and continue edit* on the configurable product before adding any associated products**, otherwise the quick create form does not show in the associated products tab.